# How to exclude an element from jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

when a table is being hovered, I have a function that adds a certain class to some element.

In that table, I want this behavior for all elements except one.

therefore in the code, I included `th,td,td span,td p,td div.good`,

But - I have a specific span (`<span class="foo">`) inside the table which I want to exclude, how can I do it?

(I'm not a JS coder so after looking in previous q's, still not sure about the most recommended way to do this in my context)

Code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function(){
    $('th,td,td span,td p,td div.good').mouseenter(function(){
        $(".light").addClass('altbg')
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(".light").removeClass('altbg')
    });
});
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it's possible to use `.not()` to exclude a set of elements from an existing selector, arguably your code is inefficient because it registers the two event handlers against a large set of elements and the callbacks will be invoked repeatedly as you move your mouse around the table.

Consider this, instead:

```
$('table,.foo').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) {
    $('.light').toggleClass('altbg');
});
```

There are only two elements listening for the mouse events - the table itself, and the span you wish to ignore.  Since you cannot reach the inner span without crossing the table this will produce the desired effect.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/eecqkx6v/

Comment: Nice, in that case though, how can I exclude two elements for example (both `.foo` and `.bar`)?

Comment: @rockyraw just add `.bar` to the selector, it'll still work so long as `.bar` isn't contained inside `.foo` (or vice-versa).  I've updated the fiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain the logic in `('table,.foo,.bar')`? I thought the first field is the "positive" element, and second field is the excluded elements, whereas the comma seperates them. but now with two commas, how does it tell which one to be included and which to exclude?

Comment: @rockyraw it depends on your DOM layout (hence my note above about this not working if `.foo` and `.bar` are nested).  It works because when you first touch the table the class gets added.  If you then enter either inner element the class gets removed.  Once in those elements, the `mouseleave` when you leave causes the class to get added again, and then finally when you leave the table it'll be removed again.  The order in the selector doesn't actually matter.

Comment: @rockyraw if `.bar` was nested inside `.foo` the sequence would go `OFF -> ON -> OFF -> ON` as you move from the `outside -> table -> .foo -> .bar`.  When they're not nested it just goes `OFF -> ON -> OFF` as you go `outside -> table -> (.foo | .bar)`.  I, umm, hope that's clear!!

Answer (score 2):

Use the jquery `.not` method to exclude elements

```
$('th,td,td span,td p,td div.good').not(".foo")
```

[jQuery .not documentation](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Also you do not have to use both the `.ready` method along with the passing a function to `$()` they will do the same thing.

```
$(function(){
    $('th,td,td span,td p,td div.good').not(".foo").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".light").addClass('altbg')
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(".light").removeClass('altbg')
    });
});
```

is all you need